# Movie where a little girl dies and becomes a robot

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw this movie only once back in the very late 90s or very early 2000s (2000 - 2001), I can't really remember when since I was about 5 years old at the time. This is a movie in which the protagonist is a boy (I think he is about 8 or 9). Here are a few points I remember about the movie:

- The movie is animated.
- There is a scene in which the boy's face is cut and he starts bleeding.
- The boy has a sister (I can't tell if she is the same age or older, but she is a little girl). I think she has blonde hair.
- I believe the plot setting is in the distant future.
- There is a scene where both the girl and the boy are hanging from the ledge of a very tall platform in danger of falling off. The height of this platform is so high that it extends into the clouds (they are outside). When the boy looks down he cannot see anything but cloud.
- I think the girl was holding onto the foot of the boy until she eventually let's go (because she couldn't hold on any longer). This was near the end of the movie.
- The boy survives. He believes the sister is gone but he discovers later on that she was able to be saved by a scientist by implanting her remains into a robot girl body (this was pretty disturbing to me as a kid).
- In the end the boy is standing next to the girl. At first this robot girl seems lifeless as she was just standing and giving no sign that she remembers anything that has happened, not even her own brother. I think I remember the boy showing the robot his hat to see if it evokes any response. I don't remember if it did but something in me says it didn't.

Does anyone have a clue what this movie could be? Give me anything you've got that's even close.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That could be the animated [Metropolis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis_(2001_film)), (2001).

> Duke Red, the 'unofficial' ruler of Metropolis, has overseen the
> construction of a massive skyscraper called the Ziggurat, which he
> claims will allow mankind to further extend its power across the
> planet.
>
> ...
>
> Duke Red has hired Laughton to build an advanced robot modeled and
> named after Red's deceased daughter, Tima.

So Tima is a robot from the start, but doesn't know it until late in the movie.

> Tima falls off the tower. Kenichi tries to pull her up using one of
> the cables still grafted to her. As the cable begins to fray, Tima
> remembers the time Kenichi taught her grammar and asks Kenichi, "Who
> am I?" before she slips and falls to her death. The Ziggurat
> collapses, destroying a large part of Metropolis.
>
> The next morning, Kenichi searches the ruins and encounters a group of
> robots that have salvaged some of Tima's parts in an attempt to
> rebuild her.